# minimizer of c/x

Tags: optimization

It seems to me that the solution to the optimization over $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n$
\begin{align}
& \underset{\lambda}{\arg\min} \sum_i c_i/\lambda_i\\
\textbf{s.t } & \sum_i \lambda_i = 1\\
& \lambda_i \geq 0
\end{align}
where $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $c_i \geq 0$, is $\lambda_i = \frac{c_i}{\sum_i c_i}$, but I'm having trouble showing so... Is this the correct minimizer? How might it be derived?

Comment: What is the meaning of arg?

Comment: @DBF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max#Arg_min

Comment: I see, so it is the pre-image set of the min of the upper expression. Thanks.

Comment: @DBF The variables are all real numbers I mean to minimize the sum as written. Although I'm not entirely sure what/why you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a minimization problem with a constraint, namely that $\sum \lambda_i =1$. Use Lagrange multipliers to write:
$$f(\lambda, \Lambda)=\sum \frac{c_i}{\lambda_i}+\Lambda\left(\sum \lambda_i-1\right)$$
The minimum will be achieved when:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda_i}=0,\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \Lambda}=0$$
Or:
$$-\frac{c_i}{\lambda_i^2}+\Lambda=0 \ \to \ \lambda_i=\sqrt{c_i/\Lambda}$$
$$\sum \lambda_i = 1 \ \to \ \Lambda=\left(\sum \sqrt{c_i}\right)^{2}$$
So that the minimum is achieved when:
$$\lambda_i =\frac{\sqrt{c_i}}{\sum \sqrt{c_i}}$$
Note that this is your solution if $c_i\to c_i^2$.

Comment: excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By Cauchy Schwarz inequality we have

$$\sum \frac{c_i}{\lambda_i} \cdot \sum \lambda_i \ge \left(\sum \sqrt{c_i} \right)^2$$

and equality is possible if $\lambda_i^2$ is proportional to $c_i$ or if $\lambda_i = \dfrac{\sqrt{c_i}}{\sum \sqrt{c_i}}$

Comment: nice solution! thanks.